# Is there any API service to filter out json data?

Tags: json, serverless

Is there any service that would filter-out unnecessary data from JSON from an API so I need not to deploy a server only for this task?

I develop for wearables. The [current JSON data from API](https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58) is too big for the wearables to handle: they run out of memory. I need to remove unnecessary data so the wearable don't run out of memory.

Is there any service to do such task so I need not to care about the server development and maintenance?

Simple white-list of identifiers not to be filtered-out would do the trick.

Comment: I don't familiar with any resource of aws to do so beside of lambda function, but if you want, specify the whole flow and maybe we can find out a workaround for that.

Comment: Thank you @ShaharYakov I described it on https://github.com/myneur/late/issues/23 below a "Suggested flow" headline.
Thanks for your ideas.